# How to run Percona with WampServer on Windows XP?

Tags: mysql, windows-xp, wamp

I was wondering if anyone knows if its possible to install Percona (mysql replacement) and use it with WampServer on a Windows XP machine. If so, does anyone know where to start?

Comment: Where to start? Hmm. I'd suggest reading the documentation.

Comment: Why was this question migrated? Sounds like a server problem to me.

Comment: Since when is this ancient Windows XP considered a Server OS? Sounds like it never fits somewhere beyond trash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never done it, however, I suggest that you download the source and try compiling it under Windows (refer to the MySQL documentation).
But keep in mind that Percona Server is optimized for Linux and there is not an official Windows build... this means that it could not work, or it may have heavy limitations on Windows.

However, you can also try MariaDB. There are official Windows binaries with an install wizard, and it works on XP. MariaDB also includes XtraDB (Percona's InnoDB fork) and many Percona's patches.